# Getting the name of the variable during whose processing an exception has occurred?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, .net-4.0, .net-4.5

I have this function which I use for my validation

```
    public void Validate()
    {
        Action<List<Field>> validateFields = (field) =>
            {
                if (field != null && field.Any())
                {
                    field.ForEach(x => x.Validate());
                }
            };

        new List<List<Field>> { this.PersonElements, this.ContactElements, this.MiscElements }.ForEach(x =>
            {
                try
                {
                    validateFields(x);
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    Log.ErrorFormat("An exception has occurred while validation of {1} : {0}", e, x.ToString()); // print something as x.Name.ToString());
                    throw;
                }
            });
    }
```

The problem is with this line:

```
  new List<List<Field>> { this.PersonElements, this.ContactElements, this.MiscElements }.ForEach(x =>
```

I need to (in case an exception has occurred) log something as

An exception has occurred while trying to process "PersonElements / ContactElements / MiscElements" depending upon during which validation an exception has occurred.

How to get the list variable name in case of an exception occurring during its processing ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You could use a `List<Tuple<String, List<Field>>>` and store the element's name in the string part.

Comment: @NicoSchertler: seems logical to me. Thanks.

Comment: @NicoSchertler: Consider posting it as an answer, i ll accept it. BTW, able to achieve that.. thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Variable names are only meaningful in their context. The same object could be accessed with different variables. So it is reasonable to provide the name of the collection in a type like a `Tuple<String, List<Field>>`.

```
new List<Tuple<List<Field>>> { Tuple.Create("PersonElements", this.PersonElements), ... }.ForEach ( 
    ...
    validateFields(x.Item2);
    ...
    Log.ErrorFormat("An exception has occurred while validation of {1} : {0}", e, x.Item1);
```